# Jquery Tool tip for HTML contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, tooltip

1, I downloaded the all these three files(JS and CSS) in my local system and tried it is not working as it is directly referring from URLS.

2, Even If i use URL src and href it is not working with the IE.IE also not saying any error.

Please help me to know what am doing wrong.

**PART 1 :**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/css/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css" />
<script src="jquery/js/jquery-1.9.0.js"/></script>
<script src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js"></script>
```

**PART 2 :**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

**HTML CODE :**

```
![<script>
$(function () {
    $(document).tooltip({
        content: function () {
            return $(this).prop('title');
        }
    });
});
</script>
<style>

.tooltip
{
  background-color:#F8D2DA;
}
.tooltipqty
{
  text-align:right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p><label for="age">Your age:</label><input id="age" 
title="<table class='tooltip'><tr><td class='tooltipqty'>20.00</td><td>31-01-2013</td></tr>
<tr><td class='tooltipqty'>0.02</td><td>01-01-2013</td></tr></table>" />
</p>
</body>][1]
```

Comment: that is also not working with IE the same Dude........

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$(this).prop('title')` with `$(this).attr('title')`.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SZexS/)

---

Didn't see it was IE related. Didn't know either that jsfiddle had problems in IE 8 ...

Comment: sorry to say this that link u mentioned is not opening in IE 8 it shows error ......